# Display only first of duplicate column values

Tags: php, mysql, database

How to query for erase the view below?

```
+-------------------+------------+
| Order_id          |   Weight   |
| 20                |          4 | 
| 21                |          5 | 
| 22                |          2 | 
| 22                |          2 |
+-------------------+------------+
```

To be like this:

```
+-------------------+------------+
| Order_id          |   Weight   |
| 20                |          4 | 
| 21                |          5 | 
| 22                |          2 | 
| 22                |            |
+-------------------+------------+
```

When displaying results but not entered into the database.

Comment: You want to show order_id 22 twice but 9nly show the weight once? What does your query look like right now? (Please edit your question to include the SQL statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is:

```
select DISTINCT order_id, weight from xyz
UNION
select order_id, null from xyz
group by order_id, weight
having count(*) > 1
Order by weight desc;
```

The 1st select statement will display all the unique values and 2nd one will retrieve only the repeated values.

In your required output table, it seems like you want to display all the non-repeated rows and the 1st column value of repeated rows but not 2nd column value. The above query will allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is how to do it:

```
SELECT
   Order_id,
   Weight,
   if(@order_id = Order_id, '', Weight) as no_dup_weight,
   @order_id := Order_id as dummy
FROM      Table1
ORDER BY  Order_id asc;
```

You basically need to check to see if the previous `Order_id` is the same as the current, and if they are, output an empty field.

Here is an [SQLFiddle demonstrating the solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/989b47/12).

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need 2 rows for the dupes?  Can't you just use the DISTINCT clause as per http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Or is it important to know what has duplicates. In which case you should look into the GROUP BY clause